# rename multiple file in a sequence c# or c++

Tags: c#, c++, rename

How can I rename multiple files like this:

```
file.txt , anotherfile.txt , log.txt
```

into something like this :

```
file1.txt , file2.txt , file3.txt
```

How can I do this in c# or in c++ ?

Comment: Do you need to do it in c# or c++?  This could easily be done in a shell script with much less effort.  If it doesn't need to be done in c# or c++, are you running linux or windows?

Comment: C++ doesn't have a notion of file names and directories in the language, so you'll need a platform-dependent solution (or Boost).

Comment: `man prename` if you are on linux ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`File.Move Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) as:

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = GetFilesToBeRenamed();
int i = 1;
foreach(FileInfo f in files)
{
    File.Move(f.FullName, string.Format("file{0}.txt", i));
    i++;
}
```

And if `f` is a fullpath, then you can do this instead:

```
File.Move(f.FullName, 
         Path.Combine(f.Directory.ToString(), string.Format("file{0}.txt", i));
```

Comment: Hi thank you all for your answers but i think that i am going with Nawaz

Answer (score 1):

This would work in you're using an sh-based shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
FEXT="txt"      # This is the file extension you're searching for
FPRE="file"     # This is the base of the new files names file1.txt, file2.txt, etc.
FNUM=1;         # This is the initial starting number

find . -name "*.${FEXT}" | while read OFN ; do
    # Determine new file name
    NFN="${FPRE}${FNUM}.${FEXT}"
    # Increment FNUM
    FNUM=$(($FNUM + 1))
    # Rename File
    mv "${OFN}" "${NFN}"
done
```

The script in action:

```
[james@fractal renfiles]$ touch abc.txt
[james@fractal renfiles]$ touch test.txt
[james@fractal renfiles]$ touch "filename with spaces.txt"
[james@fractal renfiles]$ ll
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 james james   0 Sep  3 17:45 abc.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 james james   0 Sep  3 17:45 filename with spaces.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 james james 422 Sep  3 17:41 renfiles.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 james james   0 Sep  3 17:45 test.txt
[james@fractal renfiles]$ ./renfiles.sh 
[james@fractal renfiles]$ ll
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 james james   0 Sep  3 17:45 file1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 james james   0 Sep  3 17:45 file2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 james james   0 Sep  3 17:45 file3.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 james james 422 Sep  3 17:41 renfiles.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

In c++, you will eventually use

```
std::rename(frompath, topath);
```

to perform the action.  TR2 proposal N1975 covers this function.  However, until then, use boost::rename for the immediate future, and tr2::rename for the period after approval before final placement.

Loop through and use whatever names you want.  Don't quite know if you're trying to add numbers, because the current question says 1, 2, 2.

Answer (score 0):

In c# you can use [File.Move(source, dest)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx)

Of course you can do it programatically:

```
string[] files = new string[] {"file.txt" , "anotherfile.txt" , "log.txt"}:
int index = 0;
string Dest;
foreach (string Source in files)
{
   if (!Files.Exists(Source )) continue;
   do {
       index++;
       Dest= "file"+i+".txt";
   } while (File.Exists(NewName);

   File.Move(Source , Dest); 
}
```